# Error installing 64 bit Windows on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I've installed a Headless VirtualBox on my Centos 6.4 x86_64 box, and installed phpvirtualbox.  I've inserted my Windows 7 64bit disk in the CD drive of the physical host, and created a virtual server, and used phpvirtualbox to start the virtual server.  As seen by the below screenshot, I receive an error as it appears my VirtualBox is 32 bit and not 64 bit.  How do I resolve this error?

```
[root@desktop ~]# uname -m
x86_64
[root@desktop ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64
[root@desktop ~]#
```

[image: screenshot]

EDIT to provide information requested by week:

```
[root@desktop ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "vmx|svm"
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
[root@desktop ~]#
```

Comment: Have you enabled the virtualisation extensions within your bios?

Comment: @Ramhound.  I do not believe so.  How can I tell if it is?  Thank you

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "vmx|svm"`

Comment: @user1032531 - You access the BIOS and enabled it?  You provided no information about the host system so specific instructions is not possible to provide.

Comment: @week Please see the output added to the original post.

Comment: @Ramhound.  What host information do I need to provide?  How do I access the bios if I do not have a keyboard/monitor directly connected to the server? Thank you

Comment: What about `VBoxManage -v`?

Comment: @user1032531 - If its disabled I don't know any method to enable it that doesn't involve getting access to the BIOS.

Comment: @week [root@desktop ~]# VBoxManage -v
4.3.0r89960
[root@desktop ~]#

Comment: Add `.log` file from that VM. It's located somewhere in `~\.VirtualBox`.

Comment: @week.  Please see http://pastebin.ca/2477250

Comment: On line 376. there's `64bitEnabled 0`, don't know why. But you may try `VBoxManage setextradata <yourvmname | global?> VBoxInternal/HM/64bitEnabled 1`

Comment: @week.  Gave it a try, but no success.  Frustrating :(

Comment: Did you check if that setting changed? `VBoxManage getextradata <yourvm | global> enumerate` and in log.

Comment: @week.  I had done the global option, not the vm specific option.  I checked the log, but didn't check using enumerate until getting your comment.  I get `[root@desktop Logs]# VBoxManage getextradata global enumerate
Key: VBoxInternal/HM/64bitEnabled, Value: 1`.  Windows still throws the same error, however.